# Being able to stop you long time best friend's suffering yourself?

Tags: diseases

My best friend is 14 yrs old and she's uncomfortable and crying and yelping all the time practly. I've taken her several places and all they want to do is give her pain pills I'm so distraught myself by her suffering. I want so much to stop her pain and suffering. She's my ride or die best friend we have been through so much together. All I want to do is give her what she deserves. To stop suffering, how can I do this myself. Please help me end her suffering and pain. Yes I know it's going to be hard for me, but its harder for me now watching and hearing pain and suffering now.

Comment: Don't. As hard as it is, your vet probably knows how to do it with the least pain.

Comment: First try the pills the vet gives you for a week or two. Only if they don't improve the situation, return to the vet and explain in more detail how your friend is suffering and that the meds don't work. Please understand that putting a pet to rest is a hard thing to do, even for a vet. You must explain to them that you want to end the suffering of your friend instead of just getting rid of an unwanted pet.

Comment: I'd also add that if something goes wrong if you're trying to do this yourself, it could be a lot worse. As the others say, this is a terrible situation and I'm sorry to hear how hard it is for you but, for the good of your friend, let the professional do their job.